# cs1690 defining a member for object c#

Tags: c#, field, warnings

```
double x1, y1, z1;
form main;
public points(form amain)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.main = amain;
    x1 = main.info.tip.X;
    y1 = main.info.tip.Y;
    z1 = main.info.tip.Z;
}
```

Accessing a member on 'app.form.info' may cause a runtime exception because it is a field of a marshal-by-reference class.

How can I fix this?

Comment: so.... does `x` equal `x1`? You might want to give us the actual code and more reference information.

Comment: why has it been given -3? dont understand. is declaring an object of a type so easy?

Comment: yes.. x= x1... it had been edited...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private state set2;    
public void set1()     
{    
set2 = main.info;    
}
```

here  refers to the class that is defined by the object info.
Source : Fundamentals of Computer Programming with CSharp by Nakov